# Win2003: How to trace who alter a object

Tags: windows-server-2003

In Win2003, how can I trace who delete or modify a file?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to enable the following GPO Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Audit Policies -> Audit object access

This will generate a log entry in the security log every time someone does a file operation (among others)

This **will** generate a ton of logs, you'll probably have to ship them to a machine dedicated to managing logs, or increase the size of your security log.

Comment: Hi, I changed the default log file location, with regedit, to somewhere else, but EventLog seemed loading default file location to continue with work.